# I am getting this error when I am trying to create a SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, stored-procedures

I am new to using procedures and I am trying to create a simple one, but I get an error. The SQL statement that I want to run within the procedure works as it should, but I am not sure how to make it into a functioning procedure.

I'm using a DBeaver to write my scripts with a MS Access database. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE meets_Requirements
AS
    SELECT 
        Client.`ClientNo`, Client.`MaximumRent`,  
        Client.`PreferredAccomodationType` AS `PrefType`, 
        Property.`PropertyNo`, Property.`MonthlyRent`, 
        Property.`PType` AS `PropType`
    FROM 
        `Client` 
    JOIN 
        `Property` ON Property.`MonthlyRent` < Client.`MaximumRent` 
                   AND Property.`PType` = Client.`PreferredAccomodationType` 
    WHERE 
        `ClientNo` = 1
GO;


EXEC meets_Requirements
```

This is the error I get:

[image]

Comment: Ms-access and backticks? Admittedly, last time I had to work with access was way back when 2010 was till new and shiny, but still... Does it even support stored procedures? Back then it didn't...

Comment: Its possible that it doesn't support it, I haven't found anything saying whether it does or not. The backticks can be used, but aren't necessary in this code

Comment: Access does not support SQL like that (stored procedures). I have never seen backticks in Access SQL. Use [ ] as delimiters when object names include spaces and/or punctuation/special characters or are reserved words.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to create a procedure this way in MS Access, then you need to set the option for "SQL Server Compatible Syntax (ANSI 92)" in the database under File | Options | Object Designers.